What is the RCF of $\frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{(x^4-1)} \oplus \frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{(x^2(x-1))}$ with linear transformation t given as multiplication by x?
The Question:
Consider the $\mathbb{Q}[x]$-module
$M = \frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{
(x^4 − 1)} ⊕ \frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{
(x^2(x − 1))}$.
Let $V$ be the vector space obtained from $M$ by restriction of scalars along the obvious inclusion
$\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}[x]$, and let $t : V \to V$ be the linear transformation given by multiplication by $x$. Find,
with justification, the rational canonical form of $t$.
I am studying for my qualifying exam and this question comes from a previous qualifying exam and is meant to be done by hand on pencil and paper.
My attempt:
We can see that the elementary divisors are $(x^2+1),(x+1),x^2$ and two copies of $(x-1)$. If we rewrite this into invariant factor form we have $$\frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{(x-1)} \oplus \frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{(x^6-x^2)} $$ We can then find a basis for this vector space. The correct basis is $\{(1,0),(0,1),(0,x),(0,x^2),(0,x^3),(0,x^4),(0,x^5)\}$. I then found the matrix generated by $t$ by observing what $t$ does to each basis element. This gave me the 7x7 matrix $$A =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
The next steps I believe would be to do $xI-A$ and compute the Smith normal form.
I believe the correct rational canonical form just is $$\begin{bmatrix}
C(x-1) & 0\\
0 & C(x^6-x^2)
\end{bmatrix}$$ where $C(p(x))$ is the companion matrix of $p(x)$. Which is the matrix I just found with the linear the transformation. The issue is I do not understand why this is. I believe it has something to do with the fact that for linear transformations we must have xv=t(v). Is this correct and if so why? If not could someone explain how to find the RCF of t efficiently?
Edits/Progress:
I fixed the basis as per rso's comment

I think that the smith normal form may be easy enough to compute, although if I get what I suspect that doesn't really answer why the answers is just the companion matrix of the invariant factors of M.

I think your basis is not a basis since I think M is 7 dimensional. The basis I think you want is ${(1,0),(0,1),(0,x),\ldots,(0,x^5)}$. The action of $x$ should then be block diagonal with the two companion matrices you mentioned.

Thank you! That was preventing me from understanding how to find the correct answer. I believe I now see what is happening!

Yes the solution is $$\begin{bmatrix}C(x-1) & 0 \\ 0 & C(x^6-x^2)\end{bmatrix}$$ where $C(p(x))$ is the companion matrix of $p(x)$.
As you noted the matrix you get from $t$ is already in rational canonical form. Taking the smith normal form of a matrix in rational canonical form is redundant. The RCF already encodes the invariant factors. Finding the smith normal form of a matrix in RCF gives you those invariant factors as polynomials back.
$t$ in this case happens to conveniently work out so that you do not need to compute the smith normal form of a large matrix.
